# Session issue with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting php session error on my live developed using codeigniter 2.0

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_vqp5n2k3f45mjqbh4sudkfesa6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
Filename: libraries/phpsession.php
Line Number: 8

Not getting exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions on `/var/lib/php/session` (which appears to be your current session path). Specifically, the owner and group. It needs to be accessible by the web server. See [this post, showing a similar issue that was a result of switching web servers without changing the ownership](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-beware-of-default-php-session-path-permission.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on your session_start path you configured in php.ini. That look slike your issue